# Trying to identify the species to which this vertebrae belongs

Tags: species-identification, bone-biology, bone

Found vertebrae in the "graveyard of the Atlantic" (on account of the 5,000+ shipwrecks since the 1520's) off Frisco/Hatteras, North Carolina. Tried searching online but not finding any perfect patches (although some were close with some seemingly minor differences to the untrained eye). Any ideas would be much appreciated. I have images from every angle and can take specific images if instructed on exactly what is needed. This is new for me and I am unsure who to contact if this is fruitless. If (fairly certain) identification is not possible from the image(s) please comment with any suggestions on my next contact.

[image]

Comment: I don't see any images in your question, so it is completely unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Another question about bones refers to this [bone ID site](http://www.boneid.net/search/) which you might find helpful.

Comment: Please add more photos (one from top, bottom, front, back and each of the sides) and measurements/dimensions. Thanks.